# Questions regarding dot product (possible textbook mistake)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

I am given the following exercise:

> Show that $\Vert \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} \Vert = \Vert
>  \overrightarrow{a} \Vert + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert $ if and
>   only if $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ are parallel and
>   point to the same direction. Also, show that $\Vert \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} \Vert = \Vert \overrightarrow{a} - \overrightarrow{b} \Vert$ if and only if $\overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{b} = 0$

**Regarding the first question:**

Firstly, i feel like the first question is wrong since $\Vert \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} \Vert = \Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert $ for $\theta = 0$ or $\pi$ (so they must not necessarily point on the same direction). Is that correct?

if so, I proceeded the following way:

$$
\Vert \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 = \Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert^2 + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 \pm 2 \Vert \overrightarrow{a} \Vert \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert \cos (\theta)\\
\Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert^2 + 2 \Vert \overrightarrow{a} \Vert \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert +\Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 = \Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert^2 + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 \pm 2 \Vert \overrightarrow{a} \Vert \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert \cos (\theta)\\
\cos(\theta) = \pm 1\\
\theta = 0 \text{ or } \theta = \pi
$$

**Regarding the second question:**

$$
\Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert^2 + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 +2 \Vert \overrightarrow{a} \Vert \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert \cos (\theta) = \Vert
 \overrightarrow{a} \Vert^2 + \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert^2 -2 \Vert \overrightarrow{a} \Vert \Vert \overrightarrow{b} \Vert \cos (\theta)\\
- \cos(\theta) = \cos(\theta)\\
\cos(\theta) = 0\\
\theta = \pi/2
$$

Can someone help me with these?

Comment: if $w = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda \ne 0$ then $v$ and $w$ are parallel -- $\lambda $ may be negative.

Comment: Not an algebraic proof, but for the 2nd question: $\|\vec{a}+\vec{b}\|$ and $\|\vec{a}-\vec{b}\|$ are the lengths of the two diagonals of the parallelogram having $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as adjacent sides. These diagonals have the same length if and only if the parallelogram is a rectangle; but a parallelogram is a rectangle if and only if two adjacent sides are perpendicular, which is exactly the condition $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}  = 0$. (This geometric argument does not strictly apply when either of the given vectors is $\vec{0}$.)

Comment: As an algebraic proof of the 2nd, it's easier to work with the condition $\|\vec{a}+\vec{b}\|^2 = \|\vec{a}-\vec{b}\|^2$ that's equivalent to $\|\vec{a}+\vec{b}\| = \|\vec{a}-\vec{b}\|$. Then use $\|\vec{v}\|^2 = \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$. Then you may avoid all use of the angle $\theta$.

Comment: @murray can you explain further your last comment? It seems like a great solution.

Comment: @Thomas in his answer already showed use of the identity $\|\vec{v}\|^2 = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$ to expand $\|\vec{a} + \vec{b}\|^2$. Do same thing with $\|\vec{a} - \vec{b}\|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your questions can be answered using the fact that
$$
\lVert a\rVert^2 = a\cdot a
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert a + b\rVert^2 &= (a + b)\cdot (a + b) = \lVert a\rVert^2 + \lvert b\rVert^2 + 2a\cdot b.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first question is valid. For instance, if we let $0\neq b = -a$, then $||a+b|| = 0 \neq ||a||+||b||.$ So, $a$ and $b$ must point in the same direction.

As for a proof of the first statement: going backwards, assume $a$ and $b$ point in the same direction, i.e. (without loss of generality) $b = ca$ for some scalar $c\geq 0$, and so $$||a+b|| = ||a+ca|| = (1+c)\cdot||a|| = ||a||+||ca|| = ||a||+||b||$$

Now assume $||a+b||=||a||+||b||.$ The left hand side is equal to $\sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2+2(a\cdot b)}$. So squaring both sides of the original equation and cancelling like terms, we get $a\cdot b = ||a||\cdot ||b||$, and so $b = ca$ where $c \geq 0$.

As for the second question, we can similarly expand $||a+b||=||a-b||$ to obtain $\sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2+2(a\cdot b)} = \sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2-2(a\cdot b)}$, and so $a\cdot b = 0$. And for proving this in the other direction, simply follow those steps backwards.

Your approach is more or less valid (depending on what sort of math class you're in), but the angles are unnecessary and should be avoided if possible.